# Python: problem when i use elements of a loop inside a SQL code. Error: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, sqlite, for-loop

I would like to use `every_letter` in Sql code. I used a loop to extract individually
the `letters` and use them individually in the SQL code. But I had this error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I specify that `letters = [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',)]` must remain like this without changes in brackets. `letters` is actually the result of a previous cur.execute. I get it with letters = cursor_test.fetchall() following a `scrape`

As you can guess, I want to use each letter individually in the sql code. So once the sql code for `a`, once the sql code for `b`, once the sql code for `c`, etc etc: automatically, without manually specifying the letter

What am I doing wrong?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('...')
cur = conn.cursor()

letters =  [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',)]

for every_letter in letters:
    print("every_letter: ", every_letter)

    cur.execute('''SELECT name, example1, example2
               FROM TableExample
               WHERE name = ?''', [every_letter])
```

Comment: `letters =  [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',)]` Are you aware that this makes a list of one-element tuples?  Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes. letters is actually the result of a previous cur.execute. I get it with letters = cursor_test.fetchall() following a scrape

Comment: The error happens because sqlite can't use a tuple value in a `WHERE column = value` clause.  Which makes sense, because `value` is supposed to be one single thing (a string, or an integer, etc.).  Using a tuple of values in that context makes no sense.

Comment: @JohnGordon I know that using a tuple of values doesn't make sense. As mentioned, it is the result of scraping and I can hardly modify it. I'm looking for a way to extract each value from the tuple individually and pass it into the sql code. It's possible?

Comment: I think it will work if you just pass `every_letter` as the query argument, without the square brackets.

Comment: _it is the result of scraping and I can hardly modify it_ Why not?  It's just a variable.  You should be able to modify it however you like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is trying to do is pass a `tuple` to the query. `letters` is of type `list[tuple[str]]` The error you get implies that, precisely, `tuple[str]` is probably not supported.

**Are you trying to pass the `tuple` ? or do you just want to pass a *string literal* in the form of "('a',)"?**

In the later case, you should wrapp each element in the list in string quotes.

```
letters = ["('a',)", "('b',)", "('c',)", "('d',)"]
```

That way, when you iterate over every element in `letters`, you are iterating over a list of strings that can be handled by the `execute` method.

**If, on the other hand, you needed to access the underlying element inside those tuples, you could use `comprehensions`.**

```
letters = [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',)]
letters_unpacked = [l for l, in letters]
```

and iterate over the unpacked list.

*Note that those two statements can be combined if, for example, you are given the list and not hard-coding it.*

```
letters = [tup for tup, in someFunction()]

for every_letter in letters:
    print("every_letter: ", every_letter)

    cur.execute('''SELECT name, example1, example2
               FROM TableExample
               WHERE name = ?''', every_letter)
```

**Should the `tuple`s contains *more* than one element, you could further unpack the `tuple` in two nested comprehensions.**

```
letters = [element for element in [tup for tup, in someFunction()]]

for every_letter in letters:
    print("every_letter: ", every_letter)

    cur.execute('''SELECT name, example1, example2
               FROM TableExample
               WHERE name = ?''', every_letter)
```

[image: Screencapture of last snippet and output showing correct result]

Comment: Your solution is not good. letters is just an example for the question. In reality, letters is the result of scraping with many elements. I can't manually put quotes on all of them. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: I find your second solution more useful. In sql code should I write this? WHERE name = ?''', [letters_unpacked]). Could you show me the complete code please? (including the loop). Thank you

Comment: I see you edited your answer, but maybe you didn't read my comment. Can you show me the complete code of your second solution? Thank you

Comment: As I've written it, you should still loop through the new list. So the loop and SQL bits should stay the same.

Comment: I've edited the answer to account for the case that the `tuple`s hold more than one element .  And I've added the loop as requested.

Comment: Note that you could expand the statements as needed @Horiatiki